# How can a query return only one random row for each distinct column?

Tags: distinct

I've a table with two columns, say, column1 and column2.
Column2 is not unique.
For each distinct value of column2, I want a random row, only one row, from the table?

i.e. my result set should have as many rows as the number of distinct values of column2.

eg:

```
column1   column2
x         1
y         2
z         1
```

I want the result to be

```
column1   column2
x         1
y         2
```

or

```
column1   column2
z         1
y         2
```

Is this possible using only SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do the trick on MySQL (tested on MySQL 5):

```
select a.column1, a.column2 from (select * from foo b order by rand()) a group by a.column2;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT MAX(column1), column2 FROM yourtablename GROUP BY column2`

Comment: Does not work for me. I believe there must be a more complex but better way to acomplish that.

Comment: I want a random row. I think MAX(column1), column2 returns always a specific row.

Comment: Hmm you mean it should sometimes return (x,1) and sometimes (z,1)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column1 asc)` to pull back your row numbers and filter it that way.

You didnt mention what flavour of SQL you use and I'm recalling this from memory - but this kind of thing works in Oracle 9.